# How to get original order of eigenvalues using Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues e.g. 1, 2 and 3. I disturb its values with some noise but it is small enough to change the sequence. When I obtain the eigenvalues of this matrix they are 1,2,3 in 50% cases and 1,3,2 in another 50%. 
When I do the same thing without the noise the order is always 1,2,3.

I obtain the eigenvalues using:

```
matrix.eigenvalues().real();
```

or using:

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3d> es(matrix, false);
es.eigenvalues().real();
```

The result is the same. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "natural" order for eigenvalues of a non-selfadjoint matrix, since they are usually complex (even for real-valued matrices). One could sort them lexicographically (first by real then by complex) or by magnitude, but Eigen does neither. If you have a look [at the documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html#a1165fd63a951c6afaf239174d22e9945), you'll find:

> The eigenvalues are repeated according to their algebraic multiplicity, so there are as many eigenvalues as rows in the matrix. **The eigenvalues are not sorted in any particular order.**

If your matrix happens to be self-adjoint you should use the `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`, of course (which does sort the eigenvalues, since they are all real and therefore sortable). Otherwise, you need to sort the eigenvalues manually by whatever criterion you prefer.

N.B.: The result of `matrix.eigenvalues()` and `es.eigenvalues()` should indeed be the same, since exactly the same algorithm is applied. Essentially the first variant is just a short-hand, if you are only interested in the eigenvalues.